# Scroll to top of modal Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, modal-dialog, window, scrollto

I've got a form modal that pops up and has 4 sections to complete. Each section has a next button. I would like the next button to trigger a scrollTo(0) function, but I cannot seem to get a working solution. The last thing I have tried is a variation of window.scrollTo(), but it keeps scrolling the whole page to the top, not the modal.

Any thoughts?

**Here is my .ts file**

```
import {WindowRef} from './window-ref';
...
constructor(private winRef: WindowRef) { }
...
  toggleInfo(){
    this.infoState = this.infoState === 'active' ? 'inactive' : 'active';
    this.toggleInsurance()
    this.winRef.nativeWindow.scrollTo(0)
  }
//winRef gives me access to the window object
```

Any ideas?